# finding two drain currents

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, circuit-analysis, nmos

below I have the following problem along with the circuit's picture
[image]
[image]

My analysis is as follows:

for G and D open

\begin{equation}
I_{D1}=I_{D2}\hspace{10mm}therefore\hspace{10mm}V_{ov1}=\:V_{ov2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
V_G+0.5=0.5-V_G\hspace{5mm}therefore\hspace{5mm}V_G=0
\end{equation}
using the this equation:
\begin{equation}
I_D=\frac{1}{2}k_nV_{ov}^2
\end{equation}
we see that:
\begin{equation}
I_{D1}=I_{D2} = 0.125mA
\end{equation}

My problem is that my analytical results don't agree with my simulation results below

[image]
[image]

We see from the simulation that V_G = 0.4375 which is not zero according to my analytical work. Also, the current I_D = 0.000439453 which is not 0.125mA according to my calculations. Can somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Your analysis seems correct; I think the simulation must be wrong. Check all the settings in it.

Comment: I checked it too many times already. Can't find what is wrong with it. Also, I have used it as it's for other problems and it was giving me accurate answers

Comment: I repeated your by-hand analysis and got the same result--both transistors in saturation etc. So I am at a loss; I hope someone else comments.

Comment: One question, why does W=2 in the simulation?

Comment: Just for convenience purpose because total k_n =2mA/V^2

Comment: I'm really missing something here. kn(W/L) = 1mA/V^2 according to the problem, but you are saying kn(W/L) * 2mA/V^2 * (2/1) = 4mA/V^2?

Comment: Am sorry for this mistake, I will fix it now. But still this didn't change the results too much

Comment: Maybe there is something else. I don't know your simulation tool, so this might be a stupid suggestion, but do you set kp for the NMOS or is it kn?

Comment: Am using LTSpice, with this simulator they use kp to refer to kn prime, since kn=(kn prime)(W/L). The p in kp is used to refer to prime

Comment: Btw, I just edited the question, the correct schematic should be up by now

Comment: I am out of ideas. Good luck, and please post here if you figure it out.

Comment: @Raykh Once again wrong model try this .model n1 NMOS (LEVEL=2 KP=1m VTO=0.5) and .model p1 PMOS (LEVEL=2 KP=1m VTO=-0.5)

Comment: @G36 thank you for your comment. My current model is correct. The only mistake I have is that I forgot the minus sign for vto for the PMOS. But thank you for spotting this minor error that ruining the whole thing. Again thanks alot and I appreciate your help.

Comment: This is a resistor feedback amplifier circuit. The resistor self-biases the transistors. And the currents will be identical.